# How to get rid of time from a date column Excel?

Tags: excel, countif

So, I have an Excel file where I grab data from a Jira instance where I have some columns with dates. I'm trying to create a graph where it counts the dates based on =TODAY() formula. However, since the dates are imported along with the time stamps the =COUNTIF formula does not recognize the date unless I manually delete the time stamps, which can be a nightmare thinking that there are more than 100 cells populated with dates along with time stamps. Basically I want to know if it's a way to get rid of this time stamp and leave only the date behind. Here is a screenshot so you can understand what I want to delete. [Picture with the timestamp showing in the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNJjj.jpg)

Thanks in advance for everyone trying to help!

Comment: Use `INT` or `TRUNC` perhaps.

Comment: using `INT` or `TRUNC` as suggested by @BigBen is probably the best, however an easier way to remove the timestamps manually: first select the cells you want to remove the delete the timestamps from, then go to VBA (alt-F11) and open the immediate window (ctrl-G) and enter this command `For Each s In Selection: s.value = Int(s.value): Next`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I used for now the INT to round up the dates and it works. Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of trouble!